# Can my opponent and I decide on a victory condition to avoid a draw?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, tournament

Say I'm playing against a player and we finish game 2 with 5 minutes left in the round. If we draw, both of us will be knocked down, and most likely neither will be eligible for prizes.

I know bribery is against the rules, but could we agree (before the match starts) to something along the lines of "If we draw, whoever has fewer life points will concede so at least one of us can have a chance at prizes"?

As I understand it the answer will come down to if this is defined as collusion, but I'm having a hard time determining how Wizards defines it.

Comment: When you say "we" can have a chance at prizes, do you mean you're talking about deciding who will concede but splitting hypothetical prizes? Or do you simply mean that one of you will bow out and give the other a chance at it?

Comment: @Jefromi I mean one will bow out and give the other a chance at it. There will be no prize splitting, that I know is bribery and is illegal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bribery and Collusion do not really factor into this.  If there is no agreement (or offer) to exchange something of value for a particular match result, there is no bribery.  "Collusion" is not inherently illegal in the absence of bribery (No rule says I can't concede to my friends because they're my friends.)

You are running afoul of 'Unsporting Conduct - Improperly Determining a Winner'.  Entering into (or offering) an agreement with your opponent to choose the winner of the match by any means not included in the rules of the game is a disqualification.

Comment: Note that if, with no prior agreement, you simply choose to concede game 3 (possibly because you're lower on life, or just because you know draw or lose you're out of the running for prizes), this is fine.  Even if you're 'winning' during extra turns.  If you're in your last extra turn and you know you can't win, you can concede as a courtesy to your opponent.  Even if time hasn't even been called yet, if you look at your hand and know there's no point in playing out game three because you'll never finish it in time, you can concede to skip the pointless half-game.

Comment: As I read the player's guide (that I found here: http://blogs.magicjudges.org/whatsupdocs/mipg/4-unsporting-conduct/4-3-unsporting-conduct-improperly-determining-a-winner/ ) I'm not sure this answer is supported. The four examples they mention as against this rule are: coin flipping, dice rolling, arm wrestling, and rock-paper-scissors, and the phrase "outside-the-game" is mentioned multiple times. In fact, in single-elimination tournaments, [life total *is* the tie-breaker.](http://rules.wizards.com/rulebook.aspx?game=Magic&category=Tournament%20Policy#4522)

Comment: @corsiKa In that one special circumstance yes, but the precise phrasing in the very tournament rules document that you link to is "The result of a match or game may not be randomly or arbitrarily determined through any means other than the normal progress of the game in play. Examples include (but are not limited to) rolling a die, flipping a coin, arm wrestling, or playing any other game."  The key phrase is 'normal progress of the game in play'; 'outside the game' doesn't come into it at all.

Comment: That link is out of date.  The current wording is 'a method that is not part of the current game'.  http://wpn.wizards.com/sites/wpn/files/attachements/mtg_ipg_18july14_en.pdf

Comment: I'm just saying that because the life totals are part of the game (while rock paper scissors are not) that opens the door for confusion among players who may consider life total to be a perfectly valid victory condition when they're actually committing a penalty. This confusion could easily arise even from the July 2014 edition of the IPG.

Comment: I know the question didn't explicitly ask, but as long as we're here, could you explain what you *can* do in this kind of situation?

Comment: @Jefromi, That would make a great separate question. Ask it!

Comment: @VolleyJosh I commented because I assumed the OP was trying to figure out what they could actually do (knowing one thing you can't do isn't terribly useful), but I guess since this got accepted it really was that specific.

Comment: What you *can* do in this situation is report the true result of the match.  IPG is clear on this.  Scheming to play the tournament by your own alternate rules harms other players who are in the same situation at a different table and obey the rules.  (In practice it is in fact common for players with clearly inferior board states to scoop on turn 5 of extra turns as a courtesy in this situation.  But that is different from making an agreement to play the tournament by your own rules ahead of time.)

Comment: @Affe I mentioned in other comments that I assumed the OP would be interested in things you can do when it's obvious you're *going* to draw but haven't actually drawn yet, i.e. the kind of turn 5 concession that you mentioned. It's not like it's a surprise when the match ends in a draw, and you'll always be left with no choice but to just write that down.

Comment: @Jefromi The rules say that you can concede at any time for any reason, but then they go on to list exceptions to this rule, such as bribery, wagering, and entering into an agreement with your opponent determine the match by means not included in the rules. So rather than ask what you *can* do, it's just easier to ask what you *can't* do.

Answer (score 0):

The rules of Magic itself don't allow for players to change the win conditions. Win/lose/draw conditions are defined in the rules, and unless a tournament director decided differently, you have to play by the win/loss/draw conditions written in the regular rulebook. (And at an official MTG event, the tournament director wouldn't allow otherwise).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? It's still okay to decide, at the end of the match, to concede (getting nothing in return) and let the other player move on, right? And even to discuss who should concede, as long as it'd not done *before* the match?

Comment: @Jefromi, when you say "concede", do you mean in the sense of conceding the tournament, and not playing further matches? Or conceding the game, as in deciding to treat it as though you had lost the game? There's a difference, because once the game has ended, in a draw, you cannot then concede that game... it's already ended in a draw, too late for you to concede the game and lose.

Comment: I think the idea of the question is for one player to concede *before* the match ends in a draw - for example, if you run out of time and the last game goes to extra turns, you could concede the game/match at any time before the end of the last turn. (I do now notice it says "if we draw" not "if we're about to draw", but that's not that big a change to make, and I'm sure the OP would be happy to know what can be done in that case. Maybe I've misunderstood though!)

Comment: @Jefromi, I suppose in that case it is more of an issue of knowing specific tournament regulations (which I am not that knowledgeable about). It does sound like a form of collusion to me, though. But I was originally reading the question as basically saying that they would have a draw, but then based on criteria they had decided, one player would act as though he'd lost, and report that the other player actually won. This should be clearly illegal, as it would be falsely reporting the results of a game.

Comment: @Gendolkari While the rules don't allow for the players to change the win conditions, they do allow for a player to concede at any time *for any reason*. Without tournament rules, you could agree to flip a coin and have the loser concede the match, you could bribe, or you could just punch the other player in the face until they concede (assuming you are the stronger one).